# Error 'Unresolved reference: implementation' in build.gradle.kts file when adding Android dependencies

Tags: android, kotlin, dependencies

I'm encountering an issue in my Android project where I'm getting the error message "Unresolved reference: implementation" in the build.gradle.kts file when I attempt to add dependencies. I've included the relevant code snippets below :

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.0" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.10" apply false
}
dependencies {
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
}
```

I've already checked the syntax and structure, but I'm unable to resolve this issue. Any insights or suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is a module level `build.gradle.kts` then you should remove `apply false`.

Plugins' versions are usually set in the top-level `build.gradle.kts`, but not applied to the whole project, hence `apply false`. Then you apply plugins in the module level build scripts.

Top-level `build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.0" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.10" apply false
}
```

Module level `build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input I managed to resolve the issue. It turns out I mistakenly placed the dependencies in the top-level module instead of the module-level. Your explanation about applying plugins at the module level clarified the structure for me. thanks u for your assistance!